# Remove circles in image

Tags: image-processing

I have a stack of images that have circular reconstruction artifacts that I want to remove.

How do I detect the circles and remove their pixels (i.e. fill those pixels with 0)?

An image with the circles is shown here.

Features other than the circles should be kept in the image.

[image]

Comment: It is not completely clear what exactly you call "artifacts". Please provide also an image where the artifacts are highlighted or removed (for example, by hand).

Comment: @Chelsea you can try `DeleteSmallComponents`